# How to identify this SMD device from the code on top of the component?

Tags: surface-mount

I'm having a problem.

I need to know what kind of smd this is.
there is RC39 written on it but i can't find anything about it on the internet.
maybe someone can help me?

[image]
[image]

Comment: In the vast majority you don't and guess what it might be

Comment: What PlasmaHH says and sometimes some reverse engineering, a touch of magic and a bit of common sense might help you identify the type of device (NPN, PNP, MOSFET, or IC).

Comment: You google RC39 SOT23 and the second hit confirms the answer. (The first is misinformation, it's incompatible and the device markings don't match)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an SPX5205M5-3.3. A low dropout linear regulator.

[Link to datasheet](https://www.exar.com/content/document.ashx?id=618)

[image: Extraction from datasheet]
[image: On tape]

Comment: Is your google-fu particularly powerful or do you have a special resource you'd consider sharing which helps when looking up these obscure package markings?

Comment: @brhans. Easy. Go to bed with Google each night and include the package size in your search and the forth result is the correct one in this case. TI seem to have sponsored/keyword-spammed their way in to number one in this case, but you can filter them out manually. SMD markings codebook is helpful too.